# Issues building C++ app against AWS SDK - aws/core/Aws.h not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, aws-sdk

**RESOLUTION**

Needed to add the following to make `CMakeLists.txt` file in the project directory:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
```

I'm a little miffed that step isn't mentioned in the AWS tutorial - wasted a day and a half on that.  Anyway, thanks for listening .

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm starting to play with the AWS C++ SDK, and I'm already hitting a frustrating roadblock.

I've downloaded, built, and installed the SDK on MacOS using the procedure described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html) (starting at "Building the SDK from source").  Headers and libraries have been deployed under /usr/local by running `sudo make install`.

I've written a stupid little EC2 test program:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/ec2/EC2Client.h>
#include <iostreams>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   Aws::SDKOptions options;

   options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Aws::Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Info;

   Aws::InitAPI(options);
   {
      Aws::EC2::EC2Client my_client;
      std::cout << "created client" << std::endl;
   }
   Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);
   return 0;
}
```

Don't worry about the logic of the code, because I'm not getting that far yet.

Test program is in a directory called cpp-experiments.  At the same level, I've created a cpp-experiments-build directory.  I'm using CMake to set up the build as follows:

```
cmake -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=/usr/local ../cpp-experiments
```

which gives me the following output:

```
jbode:cpp-experiments-build john.bode$ cmake -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=../aws-sdk-cpp-build ../cpp-experiments
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 9.0.0.9000039
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/john.bode/Development/AWS/cpp-experiments-build
```

I started with the bare bones CMakeLists.txt - after some random googling here and elsewhere, I've wound up with the following:

```
# minimal CMakeLists.txt for the AWS SDK for C++
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# "my-example" is just an example value.
project(cpp-experiments)

set(AWS_CPP_SDK_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/include CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk include directories")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_CORE_LIB "-l:/usr/local/lib/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link core lib")
set(AWS_CPP_SDK_S3_LIB "-l:/usr/local/lib/libaws-cpp-sdk-ec2.so" CACHE STRING "aws-cpp-sdk link EC2 lib")

# Locate the AWS SDK for C++ package.
# Requires that you build with:
#   -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=/path/to/sdk_build
# or export/set:
#   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/sdk_build
find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)

# Link to the SDK shared libraries.
add_definitions(-DUSE_IMPORT_EXPORT)

# The executable name and its sourcefiles
add_executable(cpp-experiments cpp-experiments.cpp)

# The libraries used by your executable.
# "aws-cpp-sdk-s3" is just an example.
target_link_libraries(cpp-experiments aws-sdk-cpp-core aws-sdk-cpp-ec2)
```

So then I go into cpp-experiments-build and run `make`:

```
jbode:cpp-experiments-build john.bode$ make
Scanning dependencies of target cpp-experiments
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cpp-experiments.dir/cpp-experiments.cpp.o
/Users/john.bode/Development/AWS/cpp-experiments/cpp-experiments.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'aws/core/Aws.h' file not found
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp-experiments.dir/cpp-experiments.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cpp-experiments.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I get the same result if I run `cmake` against the SDK build directory:

```
cmake -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=../aws-sdk-cpp-build ../cpp-experiments
```

Now, per the AWS documentation, I've done everything I need to do, but clearly that's not the case - for some reason, make doesn't know where the AWS header files are.  I've tried passing `-I /usr/local/include` on the `make` command line, but that's not working either.  Could someone give me a clue of what to look for?

Comment: You can debug your include directories by running `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON` and the inspecting the generated `compile_commands.json` in your `build` folder. Find the entry for `cpp-experiments.cpp` and see what the compiler `command` is.